# Livewire Custom input

Tags: laravel

Hey guys I have some problem with livewire tables from rappsoft.

I am trying to make a filter, not on a built-in function but I want to make a custom filter from html.

This is my part script view on livewire:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 mb-2">
        <div class="form-group mb-0">
            <label class="mb-1" for="TEGU6">Search</label>
            <input type="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="TEGU6" name="search" placeholder="search" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 mb-2">
        <div class="form-group mb-0">
            <label class="mb-1" for="TEGU1">Sort by</label>
            <select class="form-control form-control-sm select2 w-100 js-select" id="brand-drop" name="lorem" data-placeholder="Sort by">
                <option></option>
                <option value="a-z">A-Z</option>
                <option value="z-a">Z-A</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that my select cannot change the table... So what do I need to do using rappsoft?

I want to make it so my custom select can listen for my method on livewire.

Comment: You dont appear to be using livewire!

Comment: so, custom field cannot work using livewire?